# UserDefaults won't recall UIPickerView didSelect Int

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to use UserDefaults to recall the users last selection in UIPickerView but the code won't take effect.

Here is the function where I try to pull the picker views didSelectRow:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data[row], forKey: "timeSelected")
}
```

Here is where I recall the key:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let triggerTimeSelected = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "timeSelected") as? Int {
        userSettingsPicker.selectRow(triggerTimeSelected, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save it `String` and read it `Int` , save it like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(row, forKey: "timeSelected")
```